# How to remove consecutive repeated word from URL using Htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

I am trying to remove a word that is repeated twice in the URL of a WordPress site. 
Please note the website is installed in a directory.
for example : https://www.example.com/website/

the link is showing as such : 
https://www.example.com/website/website/amp/postname/

and i want the result to be 
https://www.example.com/website/amp/postname/

I tried to add to my htacess the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/
RewriteRule ^/website/amp/(.*)$ amp/$1/ [L,R=301,QSA]
```

but did not work

i would appreicate it if some one could direct me in a way of solving this issue
Thanks